# Best practice for dealing with objects declared in scope of multiple namespaces

Tags: c++

So for whatever reason if you have some object declared within several nested namespaces, and you need to use it in a function outside of those namespaces, what is the best practice for dealing with the excess noise?

Is it acceptable to refactor something like:

```
void doWidgetThings
{
    NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::Widget widget1;
    NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::Widget widget2;
    //...
}
```

To:

```
void doWidgetThings
{
    typedef NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::Widget  Widget;

    Widget widget1;
    Widget widget2;
    //...
}
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question. IMO, better than type alias is a using declaration: `using NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::Widget;`.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. That's what I am not sure about, whether or not there is a particular reason to prefer one way over another, hence the term 'best practice'. If not, then it's surely opinion-based.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. This is not bad practice, because you are not exposing the namespace in a header or whatever, but only in a single function that has access to these namespaces, so I think it is proper. A typedef may compile, but it gives a semantically wrong message. You are not defining a type, you are shortening a namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `using` keyword is more idiomatic to C++, although `typedef` is completely fine. The `typedef` keyword is left for backwards compatibility and can't alias template types, thus `using` was introduced on C++11 standard. So, if you ever need to alias a template type, your code could benefit from consistency by using `using`.

You can rewrite your example like so

```cpp
void doWidgetThings()
{
    using NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::Widget;
    Widget widget1;
    Widget widget2;
    //...
}
```

If you want to rename the `Widget` type to avoid any name collision, you can write

```cpp
void doWidgetThings()
{
    using MyWidget = NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::Widget;
    MyWidget widget1;
    MyWidget widget2;
    //...
}
```

And if you happen to have a template parameter, you can also parameterize it like so:

```cpp
void doWidgetThings()
{
    template <class A> using MyWidget = NamespaceA::NamespaceB::NamespaceC::Widget<A>;
    MyWidget<int> widget1;
    MyWidget<int> widget2;
    //...
}
```